# R: environment lookup

Tags: r

I am a bit confused by R's lookup mechanism. When I have the following code

```
# create chain of empty environments
e1 <- new.env()
e2 <- new.env(parent=e1)
e3 <- new.env(parent=e2)

# set key/value pairs
e1[["x"]] <- 1
e2[["x"]] <- 2
```

then I would expect to get "2" if I look for "x" in environment e3.
This works if I do

```
> get(x="x", envir=e3)
[1] 2
```

but not if I use

```
> e3[["x"]]
NULL
```

Could somebody explain the difference? It seems, that

```
e3[["x"]]
```

is not just syntactic sugar for

```
get(x="x", envir=e3)
```

Thanks in advance, 
Sven

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These functions are different.

`get` performs a search for an object in an environemnt, as well as the enclosing frames (by default):

From `?get`:

*This function looks to see if the name x has a value bound to it in the specified environment. If inherits is TRUE and a value is not found for x in the specified environment, the enclosing frames of the environment are searched until the name x is encountered. See environment and the ‘R Language Definition’ manual for details about the structure of environments and their enclosures.*

In contrast, the `[` operator does not search enclosing environments, by default.

From `?'['`:

*Both $ and [[ can be applied to environments. Only character indices are allowed and no partial matching is done. The semantics of these operations are those of `get(i, env=x, inherits=FALSE)`.*